# Service, host_name, process_id, runtime information is not available in signalfx when using micrometer for pushing custom metrics

Tags: splunk, micrometer, spring-micrometer, signalfx, splunk-api

I am trying to send custom metrics to Splunk APM using micrometer dependencies. after adding the dependencies and setting the application properties I am Seeing metrics in the APM dashboard but Service, host_name, process_id, and runtime information are not available in SignalFx when using a micrometer.

I have added the below dependencies and application properties

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-signalfx</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>   
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Application Properties

```
management.metrics.export.signalfx.access-token={my org token}
management.metrics.export.signalfx.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.signalfx.uri={my org signalfx uri}
management.metrics.export.signalfx.source=suryatestspringapp
```

I have attached the image where Service, host_name, process_id, and runtime information is missing.

Can someone help to fix this issue?[image]